# risk of javascript injection attacks with firebase

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

I am trying to understand/anticipate the security considerations associated with using firebase as a backend.

The documents cover authenticating users and validating input, but I can not find any discussion of risk associated with malicious users trying to inject javascript into the database.

Is it possible that javascript could be included in an input field that is saved to the database that then could be executed later when that code is retrieved and displayed elsewhere?

Or is firebase escaping or sanitizing data somehow?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20150318021824/http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/xss-considerations-when-developing-with.html

Comment: firebase is a good json database as it was fast but I prefer not (option for database) when it comes to sensitive data/information. You have to strictly sanitize any input for security reasons (specially javascript stuff on inputs).

Answer (score 17):

Any database (or other storage system) can be used to store malicious code as it is inherent to their function: they just store data.

The Firebase SDKs and supported libraries (such as AngularFire, EmberFire and ReactFire) ensure that they never embed the information from the database into HTML pages unescaped. While it is always possible that we (I work for Firebase) missed something there, I don't recall that ever being reported.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I figured the answer was straight forward but I am disappointed in absence of any discussion of this in the Firebase documentation. It would be really helpful for the documentation to include a discussion of where the  responsibility lies for sanitizing data (ie database vs sdk) and what users need to keep in mind in order to avoid problems.

Comment: I would agree it is concerning that there is a distinct lack of discussion. Firebase should be explicit about this, this is a major issue with client based databases. You cannot ensure sanitisation of any data being inserted into your database (unless this is possible in the database rules). I guess we just have to sanitise output of all data.

Comment: Yes the problem with this answer is it describes firebase as simply a database or storage system, but as I understand it firebase is marketing itself as a backend. To me a backend is more than simply a database and needs to deal with security.

Answer (score 5):

You have to properly escape all user input when putting it in a webpage regardless of the backend.

Comment: The problem is with Firebase is that you cannot ensure that input is sanitised as any sanitation is done client side and therefore easily overriden.

Comment: Using the admin-sdk, you can build a firebase function that sanitizes server-side before inserting into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase offer validation of data, there you can check for injecting javascript snippets into your database.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data

And you should always sanitize your output, this is not related to Firebase but a good rule of thumb.

Comment: when you say output should be sanitised, how can one do this with firebase? any documentation or resources you recommend for how to sanitize data output?  thanks